# How to store data from ResourceBundle's and switch fast between them?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

My server program supports several languages. I know user language, so I get needed phrase through map, which initialized on starting with hardcoded data.
Source sample:

```
public class Dictionary {

    private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put("stats", new HashMap<>());
        Map<String, String> stats = map.get("stats");
        stats.put("en", "Stats");
        stats.put("ru", "Статистика");
        stats.put("hi", "आँकड़े दिखाएँ");
        stats.put("ar", "احصاء");
        stats.put("zh", "游戏统计");
        stats.put("es", "Estadística");
        stats.put("pt", "Estatísticas");
        stats.put("it", "Statistiche");
    }

    public static String getStats(String lang) {
        return map.get("stats").get(lang);
    }
}
```

I found out that Java provides ResourceBundle. How can I rewrite code with this technology considering it must be as fast as current way, i.e. store data in memory, not access everytime?

**UPDATE:**
I've tried the same way with ResourceBundle:

```
public class SuperDictionary {

    private static Map<String, ResourceBundle> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    static {
            dictionary.put("en", ResourceBundle.getBundle("Dictionary", new Locale("en")));
            dictionary.put("es", ResourceBundle.getBundle("Dictionary", new Locale("es")));
    }

    public static String getStats(String language) {
        return dictionary.get(language).getString("stats");
    }

}
```

Is it the best solution?

Comment: Yes. I've read that ResourceBundle is cached by default. It's good. So how should I organize new code? Like current version with _Map<String, ResourceBundle>_ or somehow else

Comment: You get the resource bundle by passing the locale (i.e. language): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-, then you get the translation of your "stats" key from the bundle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString-java.lang.String-.

Comment: Yeah, right. I mean is it best way?

Comment: What other way is there?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, I don't know

Comment: There isn't. My feeling is that you're overthinking things. When there is a clear, obvious way of doing something found in the documentation, you shouldn't start wondering if there is another way, and if the best way is hidden anywhere. You should just use the clear, obvious way and check that it works as you expected. It will usually be fast enough, because  Sun/Oracle engineers and documentation writers did their job correctly. Not to mention that the probability of this being the cause of a performance problem is close to 0.

Comment: Regarding your last edit: your map of bundles is unnecessary. ResourceBundle already has its own cache.

Comment: It's just for simple accessing to data: _dictionary.get(language).getString("stats");_

Comment: Why don't you use a Locale rather than a String for the language? Or, if you explicitely want to support a limited set of locales, why don't you use an enum?

Comment: Because I store two-character code of user language in database and pass it in many methods, so it's easier to store _String_, but I agree with you that _Locale_ is righter.
If I use enum how then I access to data? I know what it is but can't imagine for now. Map way looks simplest for me